# Select2 select all dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectall

I have a question regarding select2. Is it possible that we will add "Select All" on the drop down itself?

**Example:**

```
<select>
    <option value='-1'>select all</option>
    <option value='a'>A</option>
    <option value='b'>B</option>
    <option value='c'>C</option>
</select>
```

When I choose "select all" the field will display "select all" but on the background the a-c are selected.. it's seems like a trick.. hope you have a solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Select 2 is awesome, but you have a choice to use other plugin, something like this [one](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect).

Comment: @janmvtrinidad thanks for the idea but i already started using select2.. some of my forms.. but i have an issue when it has more than 10 options.. thats why i need to have a "select all" same with your example.. :(

Comment: you can disable other option when you select all to avoid overflowing in design. what you think?

Answer (score 1):

Based on http://jsbin.com/seqonozasu/1/edit?html,js,output, you can do something like this:

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require([
      'select2/utils',
      'select2/dropdown',
      'select2/dropdown/attachBody'
    ], function (Utils, Dropdown, AttachBody) {
        function SelectAll() { }

        SelectAll.prototype.render = function (decorated) {
            var $rendered = decorated.call(this);
            var self = this;

            var $selectAll = $(
                '<span class="select2-results__option select-all" aria-selected="false">Select All</span>');

            $rendered.find('.select2-dropdown .select2-results').append($selectAll);

            $selectAll.on('click', function (e) {
                var $results = $rendered.find('.select2-results__option[aria-selected=false]:not(.select-all)');

                // Get all results that aren't selected
                $results.each(function () {
                    var $result = $(this);

                    // Get the data object for it
                    var data = $result.data('data');

                    // Trigger the select event
                    self.trigger('select', {
                        data: data
                    });
                });

                self.trigger('close');
            });

            $selectAll.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
                var selectedClass = 'select2-results__option--highlighted';
                var $results = $rendered.find('.select2-results__option[aria-selected=false]:not(.select-all)');

                // Get all results that aren't selected
                $results.each(function () {
                    var $result = $(this);

                    //remove selected class
                    $result.removeClass(selectedClass);
                });

                $(this).addClass(selectedClass);
            });


            $selectAll.on('mouseleave', function (e) {
                var selectedClass = 'select2-results__option--highlighted';

                $(this).removeClass(selectedClass);
            });
            return $rendered;
        };

        $("select").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a User",
            allowClear: true,
            dropdownAdapter: Utils.Decorate(
              Utils.Decorate(
                Dropdown,
                AttachBody
              ),
              SelectAll
            )
        });
    });
```

along with css:

```
span.select2-results__option.select-all {
    display: block;
}
```

This adds all the selected elements to the select2 input.

To show "select all" rather than the element text, when you loop through the list elements on `$selectAll.click()`, add them to an array rather than triggering the `select` event, and then trigger the `select` event outside the loop, to select a dummy "select all" list item. (I haven't tried this bit, so it might not work).